# pthread_detach - segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pthreads

give advice, reading a lot on this subject, and have not found an explanation for this behavior pthread_detach ..

structure code for help:

```
#define QUEUE_SIZE 50
//...
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_t tid[QUEUE_SIZE];

//....

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
pthread_attr_t thattr;
//...
if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0) { ... exit; }

for(;;) {

if ( tn == QUEUE_SIZE ) { tn = 0; }

    while (1) {
    if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) == 0) {
    //....
    memset or other for data carg[]
    //....
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    break;
    }}
    pthread_attr_init(&(thattr));
    if (pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thattr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED) != 0) { .. error print.. }

ret = pthread_create(&(tid[tn]), &(thattr), th_logger, &carg[tn]);
    if ( ret != 0 )  { ... continue; } else {
    if ( pthread_detach(tid[tn]) != 0 ) { ...perror etc } // This is seg fault permanent
    if ( pthread_attr_destroy(&thattr) != 0 ) {  ...perror etc }
    tn++;
}

//...
} // end for(;;;)

void* th_logger(void* arg) {
    //....

    while (1) {
    if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) == 0) {
    //... read write pointer to structure data arg
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        break;
    }}
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
    //.... job and other ..
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);

    while (1) {
    if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) == 0) {
        tid[a->mutexid] = (pthread_t)NULL;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        break;
    }}
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

valgrind write:

```
==3673== Invalid read of size 4
==3673==    at 0x7BF41B: pthread_detach (in /lib/libpthread-2.5.so)
==3673==    by 0x8051152: main (in /usr/sbin/sensord-ng)
==3673==  Address 0x48 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3673==
==3673== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3673==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x48
==3673==    at 0x7BF41B: pthread_detach (in /lib/libpthread-2.5.so)
==3673==    by 0x8051152: main (in /usr/sbin/sensord-ng)
==3673==
==3673== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 19 from 1)
==3673==
==3673== 1 errors in context 1 of 3:
==3673== Invalid read of size 4
==3673==    at 0x7BF41B: pthread_detach (in /lib/libpthread-2.5.so)
==3673==    by 0x8051152: main (in /usr/sbin/sensord-ng)
==3673==  Address 0x48 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

maybe I missed something important, but I do not see any fundamental errors in your code.

Comment: You create the thread detached, and then you call `pthread_detach` on it.  Don't do that.  I don't know whether that's the cause of your problem because it's kind of pointless trying to debug pseudo code.

Comment: Also couldn't it be the thread that is to be detached already ended?

Comment: Well, what is check's is theread ended?

Comment: I'm isert before ptheread_detach(..) -> assert(&tid[tn] != NULL); - no effect...